# Speed up pandas lookup

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 pandas series: data and events.

- data is an ordered series of datapoints
- events contains indices of points of interest in data

I would like to extract a window of fixed size around each point of interest.

I came up with:

```
res = []
for k in events:
    win = data.loc[k - ticks_before:k + ticks_after].values
    res.append(win)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(res)
```

which works but is very slow. Any Panda-fu to make it fast?

Edit: found a 5x faster solution which is:

```
res = np.zeros((len(events), win_len))
i = 0
for k in events:
    res[i] = data.loc[k - ticks_before:k + ticks_after]
    i+=1

new_df = pd.DataFrame(res)
```

Any idea to make it even faster?

Below is input and output code:

**Input:**

```
data = pd.Series(xrange(200))
events = [50, 77, 98, 125, 133, 159, 161]
ticks_before = 32
ticks_after = 16
def slow_loop(data, events, ticks_before, ticks_after):
    res = []
    for k in events:
        win = data.loc[k - ticks_before:k + ticks_after].values
        res.append(win)
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(res)
    return new_df.mean()

def fast_loop(data, events, ticks_before, ticks_after):
    win_len = ticks_before + ticks_after + 1
    res = np.zeros((len(events), win_len))
    i = 0
    for k in events:
        res[i] = data.loc[k - ticks_before:k + ticks_after]
        i+=1

    new_df = pd.DataFrame(res)
    return new_df.mean()


assert(all(slow_loop(data, events, ticks_before, ticks_after) ==  
           fast_loop(data, events, ticks_before, ticks_after)))
%timeit slow_loop(data, events, ticks_before, ticks_after)
%timeit fast_loop(data, events, ticks_before, ticks_after)
fast_loop(data, events, ticks_before, ticks_after)
```

**Output:**

```
100 loops, best of 3: 3.66 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 632 µs per loop

0      82.714286
1      83.714286
2      84.714286
3      85.714286
4      86.714286
5      87.714286
6      88.714286
7      89.714286
8      90.714286
9      91.714286
10     92.714286
11     93.714286
12     94.714286
13     95.714286
14     96.714286
15     97.714286
16     98.714286
17     99.714286
18    100.714286
19    101.714286
20    102.714286
21    103.714286
22    104.714286
23    105.714286
24    106.714286
25    107.714286
26    108.714286
27    109.714286
28    110.714286
29    111.714286
30    112.714286
31    113.714286
32    114.714286
33    115.714286
34    116.714286
35    117.714286
36    118.714286
37    119.714286
38    120.714286
39    121.714286
40    122.714286
41    123.714286
42    124.714286
43    125.714286
44    126.714286
45    127.714286
46    128.714286
47    129.714286
48    130.714286
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and sample output.

Comment: I thought `pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply` could help but on second thought it doesn't. I too would like sample input and output.

Comment: How are you defining slow, compared to what?

Comment: Do you need `X` windows at the end? Where X - is the number of elements in the `events` series/array? Or do you need just one window/series with all matching elements?

Comment: I need to the windows stacked in a matrix

Answer (score 2):

here is a numpy solution which seems to be 10 times faster, compared to `fast_loop`:

```
# numpy solution
def np1(data, events, ticks_before, ticks_after):
    return pd.Series(
                np.concatenate(
                    [data.values[x - ticks_before: x + ticks_after+1] for x in events])
                .reshape(len(events), ticks_before + ticks_after+1)
                .mean(0))

# similar Pandas solution
def pd1(data, events, ticks_before, ticks_after):
    return pd.Series(
            pd.concat(
                [data[x - ticks_before : x + ticks_after +1] for x in events],
                ignore_index=True)
              .reshape((len(events), ticks_before + ticks_after +1))
              .mean(0))
```

**Timing** against 20M rows series:

```
In [440]: %timeit slow_loop(data2, events, ticks_before, ticks_after)
The slowest run took 10.67 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100 loops, best of 3: 4.7 ms per loop

In [441]: %timeit fast_loop(data2, events, ticks_before, ticks_after)
1000 loops, best of 3: 936 µs per loop

In [442]: %timeit pir5(data2, events, ticks_before, ticks_after)
1000 loops, best of 3: 436 µs per loop

In [443]: %timeit pd1(data2, events, ticks_before, ticks_after)
1000 loops, best of 3: 804 µs per loop

In [444]: %timeit np1(data2, events, ticks_before, ticks_after)
10000 loops, best of 3: 75.8 µs per loop
```

Setup:

```
In [435]: data2 = data.copy()

In [436]: data2 = pd.concat([data2] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)

In [437]: data2.shape
Out[437]: (20000000,)
```

**OLD answer:**

Timing (on another/slower machine):

```
In [353]: %timeit fast_loop(data, events, ticks_before, ticks_after)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.27 ms per loop

In [354]: %timeit np1(data, events, ticks_before, ticks_after)
1000 loops, best of 3: 222 ┬╡s per loop

In [360]: %timeit slow_loop(data, events, ticks_before, ticks_after)
100 loops, best of 3: 12.5 ms per loop
```

check:

```
In [356]: (fast_loop(data, events, ticks_before, ticks_after) == np1(data, events, ticks_before, ticks_after)).all()
Out[356]: True
```

Comment: /@MaxU Wow,  96.7 µs per loop

Comment: @Merlin, yes, I was surprised as well that `numpy` (np1) is that much faster compared to almost similar `pandas` solution (pd1)

Answer (score 1):

I give up!  I've tried a bunch of things.  Below are just a few:

```
def pir1(data, events, ticks_before, ticks_after):
    rng = np.add.outer(events, [-1 * ticks_before, ticks_after + 1])
    res = np.zeros(ticks_before + ticks_after + 1)
    for r in rng:
        res += data[r[0]:r[1]]
    res /= len(rng)
    return res

def pir2(data, events, ticks_before, ticks_after):
    rng = np.add.outer(events, [-1 * ticks_before, ticks_after + 1])
    return np.array([data[r[0]:r[1]] for r in rng]).mean(axis=0)

def pir3(data, events, ticks_before, ticks_after):
    events = np.asarray(events)
    return pd.DataFrame([data[offset + events].mean() for offset in range(-ticks_before, ticks_after + 1)])

def pir4(data, events, ticks_before, ticks_after):
    events = np.asarray(events)
    return pd.DataFrame([data[offset + events] for offset in range(-ticks_before, ticks_after + 1)]).mean(axis=1)

def pir5(data, events, ticks_before, ticks_after):
    events = np.asarray(events)
    data = data.values
    return np.dstack((data[offset + events] for offset in range(-ticks_before, ticks_after + 1))).mean(axis=1)

def pir6(data, events, ticks_before, ticks_after):
    events = np.asarray(events)
    cums = data.cumsum()
    return np.dstack((data[offset + events] for offset in range(-ticks_before, ticks_after + 1))).mean(axis=1)
```

Times: pir5 beats it a bit.

[image]

Comment: /@piRSquared  pir5--  86.7 µs per loop

Comment: @Merlin bah! my machine must be terrible.

Answer (score 0):

I believe filtering on a time index should be very efficient, with Pandas.

Something like

```
df.set_index('my_time_variable',inplace=True)
df[time - ticks_before:time + ticks_after]
```

should speed up the lookup a lot. and then you can still loop over all your dates.
Be sure to use a format for `time - ticks_before` that is recognizible by Pandas as a date, such as `'2015-05-05 13:30'`

Answer (score 0):

Simplified a bit, Question: Why is there a series of number for xxx.mean(). Mean should be one number! This is likely adding processing time.

```
 def fast_loop(data, events, ticks_before, ticks_after):
        win_len = ticks_before + ticks_after + 1
        res     = np.zeros( (len(events), win_len) )

        for k in enumerate(events):
            res[i] = data.loc[k - ticks_before:k + ticks_after]

        return pd.DataFrame(res).mean()
```